# A list of indices in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database-indexes, mongodb-indexes, database

Is there a way to see a list of indices on a collection in mongodb in shell?  i read through http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes but i dont see anything

Answer (score 150, accepted):

From the shell:

```
db.test.getIndexes()
```

For shell help you should try:

```
help;
db.help();
db.test.help();
```

Answer (score 38):

If you want to list all indexes across collections:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) {
   indexes = db.getCollection(collection).getIndexes();
   print("Indexes for " + collection + ":");
   printjson(indexes);
});
```

Comment: it works perfect

Answer (score 13):

And if you want to get list of all indexes in your database:

```
use "yourdbname"

db.system.indexes.find()
```

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you use your collection:

```
db.collection.getIndexes()
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/indexes/#information-about-indexes

Answer (score 6):

You can also output all your indexes together with their size:

```
db.collectionName.stats().indexSizes
```

Also check that `db.collectionName.stats()` gives you a lot of interesting information like paddingFactor, size of the collection and number of elements inside of it.

Answer (score 4):

Taking this one step further, if you'd like to find all indexes on all collections, this script (modified from Juan Carlos Farah's script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609667/iterate-over-all-mongo-database)) gives you some useful output, including a JSON printout of the index details:

```
 // Switch to admin database and get list of databases.
db = db.getSiblingDB("admin");
dbs = db.runCommand({ "listDatabases": 1}).databases;


// Iterate through each database and get its collections.
dbs.forEach(function(database) {
db = db.getSiblingDB(database.name);
cols = db.getCollectionNames();

// Iterate through each collection.
cols.forEach(function(col) {

    //Find all indexes for each collection
     indexes = db[col].getIndexes();

     indexes.forEach(function(idx) {
        print("Database:" + database.name + " | Collection:" +col+ " | Index:" + idx.name);
        printjson(indexes);
         });


    });

});
```

Comment: This is really helpful, but I think that `printjson(indexes);` should be `printjson(idx);`

Answer (score 0):

Using an old version of MongoDB here but [one of the top answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32230699/5418514) here **did not work for me**. This one worked:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) {
    print("Collection: '" + collection);
    print(db.getCollection(collection).getIndexes())
});
```