# In Mongo, how do I display the indexes of a collection?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-indexes, database

I just want to display all the indexes in the shell.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you want raw access to the indexes, you can query the `db.system.indexes` collection:

```
> db.system.indexes.find()
```

To find the indexes for a specific collection, you can do:

```
> db.collection.getIndexes()
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789865/a-list-of-indices-in-mongodb).