# How to test if an index is unique in Mongo on the command line

Tags: mongodb

I'm working with a collection that someone else created, and I need to find out whether an index is unique. Is there anyway to do this from the mongo shell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A list of indices in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789865/a-list-of-indices-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can search for indexes with:

`db.system.indexes.find();`

To search for a unique index:

`db.system.indexes.find({"unique": true});`

With that, you can also add more search parameters to find specific indexes by namespace, key, etc.

Edit: Relevant documentation: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Index-Related+Commands

Comment: @Sentinel: what is "this"? He posted 2 suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

```
db.<my_collection>.getIndexes()
```

If some of those indexes are unique, you will see a key named "unique" with the value **true**.