# Iterate over all Mongo database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I'm relatively new to MongoDB and I've not been able to find a solution for what I'm looking for.

I would like to iterate over all mongo databases and run some command on each collection of each database. I can run the following command to get all db names:

```js
db.runCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } ).databases.forEach(function (db) {
    print ("db=" + db.name);
});
```

But how do I "switch" database within forEach loop so I can run query against each database? I want to use something like `use db.name` within loop but that's not working.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use `db.getSiblingDB()` to switch between databases and `db.getCollectionNames()` to get the collection names. Note that you have to run the first command from the `admin` database in order to get the list of databases. A short script in the shell to achieve what you want to do would look something like the following:

```js
// Switch to admin database and get list of databases.
db = db.getSiblingDB("admin");
dbs = db.runCommand({ "listDatabases": 1 }).databases;

// Iterate through each database and get its collections.
dbs.forEach(function(database) {
    db = db.getSiblingDB(database.name);
    cols = db.getCollectionNames();

    // Iterate through each collection.
    cols.forEach(function(col) {

        // Do something with each collection.
        print(col);
    });

});
```