# How do I get all the information about an index using mongo native or mongoskin?

Tags: mongodb, mongoskin

I'm using mongoskin 1.4.4 and I'm trying to get information about whether an index is sparse, or unique, or whatever, but the method 'indexInformation' i'm using isn't returning that info.

I see here that there's a function 'getIndexes' - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/list-indexes/  but mongoskin doesn't seem to have that. I see that you can get index info from db.system, but I don't know how to access that with mongoskin either.

Does anyone know how to get more complete index information using mongo native?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2789865/1090562

Comment: Ya thanks, but none of those apply to mongo native - i'm not using the interactive shell.